For exterior (decking, siding…), how does kiln-dried copper-azole injected wood compare to acetylated wood?
I had never heard about copper-azole injected wood before. I have used thermowood in the past and found it compared very badly to acetylated wood. I'm wondering how the copper-azole injected wood compares, in term of long-term performance, maintenance requirements and how it expands/contracts due to moisture.

This is a very North American response, so might not apply to your products, but CA injected wood here is both very durable (rated for ground contact) and generally terrible as a finish surface (rough, incised, splintery) so generally not used underfoot or as cladding. Do you have access to synthetic decking such as trex or azek? It’s durable and walkable with bare feet.
